# Dynamically add input form to template based off of 'Add' button, and handle all forms with view

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I have a `Workorder` model and a `WorkItem` model. The `Workorder` model has a project number and a project manager. The `WorkItem` model has a product (which is a foreign key to another database, but I don't see how it would be relevant to the issue), a `workorder` foreign key, a quantity (relating to how many of said product is needed), and a `product_mpn` `CharField` to determine which product it should be associated with.

A `Workorder` has an unknown number of `WorkItems`, which is why the idea of dynamically created forms came to mind. The theory I had in mind was to dynamically append the form to the template on a button or link click, and when the main 'Submit' button is clicked, all `WorkItems` could be created and sent to the corresponding `Workorder`.

What would be the best approach to dynamically append forms to a template and handle the resulting data?

Comment: javascript + ModelFormset

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read about formsets, specifically inline formsets.

> Inline formsets is a small abstraction layer on top of model formsets.
>   These simplify the case of working with related objects via a foreign
>   key. Suppose you have these two models:
>
> ```
> from django.db import models
>
> class Author(models.Model):
>     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
>
> class Book(models.Model):
>     author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
>     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
> ```
>
> If you want to create a formset that allows you to edit books
>   belonging to a particular author, you could do this:
>
> ```
> from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
> BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book)
> author = Author.objects.get(name='Mike Royko')
> formset = BookFormSet(instance=author)`
> ```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Then to allow end users to dynamically add WorkItems, you should check out the django-dynamic-formset jQuery plugin  here:

https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset

Comment: I've read into inline formsets already, but maybe I skipped over something. Their descriptions for what formsets are just seem a bit vague for someome very new to Django. Thank you for mentioning dynamic-formsets, though. I will definitely look into that.